# EXCEL VLOOKUP returning #NA when IF condition specifies " "

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

> =IF(VLOOKUP(D4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]Big'!$B:$B,1,FALSE),"Project
>   BIG",IF(VLOOKUP(D4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry)
>   Specifications.xlsx]Cran'!$B:$B,1,FALSE),"Project
>   Cranberry",IF(VLOOKUP(AH4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry)
>   Specifications.xlsx]SMP BIG List'!$E:$E,1,FALSE),"Project
>   BIG(Original)",IF(VLOOKUP(AH4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14
>   (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]SMP BIG
>   List'!$G:$G,1,FALSE),"Project BIG(New)"," "))))

Above is an excel code I am using to cross check SKUs on other sheets. If the VLOOKUP is found I want the [if_true_value] to state which sheet it's on (i.e. "Project BIG") if VLOOKUP is not found the [if_false_value] runs another VLOOKUP to search another sheet. The final [if_false_value] is " " which I simply wanted a blank cell if the SKU is not found. However I am getting #N/A is the cells.

So my question: Is this a valid way of using VLOOKUP? Is it actually iterating through the true/false conditions to the end of the code? And any suggestions to improve this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If it works, it's fine. Though, personally I'd use cell("filename",d4) instead of "hard coding" the name in each Lookup results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($D4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]Big Sku List '!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),
    IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($D4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]Cranberry Sku List'!$I:$I,1,FALSE)),
    IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(AH4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]SMP BIG List'!$E:$E,1,FALSE)),
    IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(AH4,'[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]SMP BIG List'!$G:$G,1,FALSE)),
    "NO","Project BIG(NEW)"),"Project BIG(Original)"),"Project Cranberry"),"Project BIG")
```

Above is what I came up with.

The ISNA will check the value of VLOOKUP and if it is true (#N/A) it does another VLOOKUP all the way down the chain, through different sheets. Then the "False" statements tell me where the VLOOKUP was found. Verified a few of them manually, I am confident this solution works.

I thank you all and hope this is helpful for the next person!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each VLookup in NOT(ISERROR()) to achieve what you're looking for:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,sheetname!A:A,1,FALSE))),"some statement","another vlookup")
```

Answer (score 0):

Much as been already suggested, you need to check if you are returning a result. As you only want to check existance, a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is a bit of overkill. I would suggest a simpler [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) with a check to see if it is returning a row number (found) or error (not found).

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4, '[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]Big'!$B:$B, 0)), "Project BIG",
    IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4, '[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]Cran'!$B:$B, 0)), "Project Cranberry",
       IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AH4, '[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]SMP BIG List'!$E:$E, 0)), "Project BIG(Original)", 
          IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AH4, '[05.14_Wave 5 Priority 14 (Big+Cranberry) Specifications.xlsx]SMP BIG List'!$G:$G, 0)), "Project BIG(New)",
    ""))))
```

You can keep the line feeds in your formula to help you make more sense of it.

Comment: I kept the VLOOKUP but did something similar to what you suggested. Thank you!